# Is what I'm trying to do with a CollectionView and binding from a JSON response possible/dumb?

Tags: json.net, maui

I'm trying to bind images to the left column of my CollectionView but not having any luck, not even sure I'm anywhere close to how this can/should work really.  I'm able to display the Title, Username, and number of comments as expected - but can't figure out how I'm supposed to bind the images from my json, or get hold of the values.  Is what I'm attempting even possible, or is this going to require some data manipulation in the ViewModel?

I have this CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Posts}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="4"
                       Source="{Binding Image.ImageUrl}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Username}"
                       TextColor="Grey"
                       FontAttributes="None"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="3"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding NoComments}"
                       TextColor="Grey"
                       FontAttributes="None"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="3"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       Text="Comments"
                       TextColor="Grey"
                       FontAttributes="None"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

and this Json body:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": "1777541842c0b45957f881d7",
            "type": "link",
            "title": "‘Shameful loss’: wolves declared extinct in Andalucía",
            "body": null,
            "link": {
                "url": "https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2023/aug/01/wolves-declared-extinct-in-andalucia-spain-aoe",
                "hostname": "www.theguardian.com",
                "image": {
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720,
                    "size": 70842,
                    "averageColor": "rgb(18, 80, 155)",
                    "url": "/images/1001/177754183fe72063c1c3c60e.jpg",
                    "copies": [
                        {
                            "copyId": "120x120_cover",
                            "width": 120,
                            "height": 120,
                            "size": 4280,
                            "url": "/images/1001/177754183fe72063c1c3c60e.jpg?size=120x120\u0026fit=cover",
                            "objectFit": "cover"
                        },
                        {
                            "copyId": "325x250_cover",
                            "width": 325,
                            "height": 250,
                            "size": 14437,
                            "url": "/images/1001/177754183fe72063c1c3c60e.jpg?size=325x250\u0026fit=cover",
                            "objectFit": "cover"
                        },
                        {
                            "copyId": "875x500_cover",
                            "width": 875,
                            "height": 500,
                            "size": 48715,
                            "url": "/images/1001/177754183fe72063c1c3c60e.jpg?size=875x500\u0026fit=cover",
                            "objectFit": "cover"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "next": "17775178ea4e9ec53f9718d5"
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Oh yeah, and my model:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace App.Models
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

    public class Copy
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("copyId")] public string CopyId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("width")] public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("height")] public int Height { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("size")] public int Size { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("url")] public string Url { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("objectFit")] public string ObjectFit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("mimetype")] public string Mimetype { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("width")] public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("height")] public int Height { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("size")] public int Size { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("averageColor")] public string AverageColor { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("url")] public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("copies")] public List<Copy> Copies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Link
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("url")] public string LinkUrl { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("hostname")] public string Hostname { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("image")] public Image Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("username")] public string Username { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("title")] public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("body")] public object Body { get; set; }
    }

    
    public class Root
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("posts")] public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("next")] public string Next { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As per answer below, pasting this here:

```
<Image 
     Grid.RowSpan="4"
     Aspect="AspectFill"
     HeightRequest="60"
     WidthRequest="60">
     <Image.Source>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="https://discuit.net{0}">
                <Binding Path="Link.Image.LinkUrl" />
          </MultiBinding>
     </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

**FINAL SOLUTION FOR WORKING IMAGES**

```
<Image 
     Grid.RowSpan="4"
     Source="{Binding Link.Image.ImageUrl, StringFormat='https://discuit.net{0}'}"
     Aspect="AspectFill"
     HeightRequest="60"
     WidthRequest="60" />
```

Comment: the `url` field in your json only contains a path, not a hostname

Comment: also, the `url` in the json is nested `posts[].link.image.url`, so I'm not sure how you are defining the `Image.ImageUrl` property in your model

Comment: I see... that makes sense.  Am I right in thinking that means I'm going to need to build it as a variable in the ViewModel and then bind that somehow?

Comment: you can create a read-only property in your model to build the url, but based on the data I don't think you have enough information to do that.  Simply appending the path to the hostname does not give a valid image url

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to post the model.  I had changed the name from url to LinkUrl because I had multiple with the name url and was assigning and calling them out in console to see what was/wasn't in them since I still don't really know how to debug in VS.

Comment: the image urls on that article don't appear to bear any resemblance whatsoever to what is listed in the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and what I can read from you json and code, is that you want to take link.url and combine it with image.url. You can do that with `MultiBinding`. Read about [MultiBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding) I assume you got the collectionview populated and that the json deserialized everything as it should.

```xml
<Image
    Grid.RowSpan="4"
    Aspect="AspectFill"
    HeightRequest="60"
    WidthRequest="60">
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
            <Binding Path="Link.LinkUrl" />
            <Binding Path="Link.Image.ImageUrl" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think I'm going to need to MultiBind link hostname with image url (and maybe add "https://" before the hostname?  I'm not really sure if I'm trying to access them right or not either, haven't been able to spit out value to the console yet at least.  Title, Body, Username, etc. are biding correctly though and populating the collectionview - so I at least know that I'm getting the json deserialized okay.  I'll mess around with this and see if I can figure it out - thanks for pointing me at it!!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote if you like it and mark it as an answer when you have verified it. The more we upvote good answers the easier it is for others in the same situation to find it.

Comment: If you want to add protocol in front of the string to make a url you can add that to the StringFormat like this: `StringFormat="https://{0}{1}"`

Comment: Sorry, just got back to this.  I do believe this is indeed the answer I'm looking for, though I'm having issues still.  Turns out that the image is actually on the site itself, not the site it is linking to.  Could you take a look at what I've added at the bottom of my question to see if that should work (it's not)?  Also, in the example in your answer - what does that first empty set of curly braces do/mean?  Or I guess since I don't think I actually do need MultiBinding now, I should just look at StringFormat on a single element to add the https://?  Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh and I didn't really understand what I was doing with the proposed edits - and don't see a way to 'unreject' them now 

Comment: From the documentation: 
"If the format string starts with the { character, the XAML parser will confuse it for a markup extension. To avoid this ambiguity, prefix the format string with an empty set of curly braces." So only when it starts. If you have text in front of the curls it is all good.

Comment: Okay this is probably a really dumb question, but what documentation are you talking about?  I've just been using books and google 

Comment: I have a link in my answer that point to all this. [MultiBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding#format-strings)

Comment: Your update looks ok. You can use MultiBinding on Labels as well so make one and see what it says. For debugging.

Comment: Oh I see - somehow I read through it all multiple times without noticing the link!

Comment: Yes, and if you don't need multiple binding you can use it as you have done now. Good work.